# DotA: placing mines by Goblin Techies

Tags: dota

I am interested in some good strategies of playing by Techies. Mostly, what is the most profitable place for placing mines in the game beginning ? Such places as near the top/bottom shops work rarely because it's the first place where the opponents do **NOT** send their heroes having techies in opposite team. Also I wonder when it's the best time to leave the line and start patrolling over the map and mining. I understand that it of course depends on the concrete game and heroes pick, but I'm interested in opinion of experiences players.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are right, most players are aware that you will most probably place bombs on the shop area so they are carefull. However, early game, while lanning, you can notice that your creeps will go only on one half of your lane(left side on bot lane and right side of top lane). So it's a pretty good idea to place your mines anywhere in the lane on the side which is not crossed by creeps. However, you should be very carefull because by attacking an enemy hero you will provoke enemy creeps to come to you and attack you and therefore they will get outside their normal lane track. If you keep this in mind, this is a pretty good strategy to start with. Classic spots like runes will however get you a kill if the enemy player isn't cautious. If the enemy team starts buying sentry wards or gems, you might consider yourself useless. Even so, it is not the case. Use ramp fog to your advantage.
Place your mines on the upper part of any cliff. This way when the enemy comes even if it has a gem in his inventory he won't be able to see the bombs because of the fog. If they also have the map filled with observer wards, then you are pretty much screwed. In this case your only option would be a force staff. But if you want to play a good all around game, you should definately go for aghanim. On lvl 16 with aghanim the damage output of a single remote bomb is just outrageous. In team fights just place bomb and instant detonate. If the opposing team has a few agi/int or non-tank heroes, I am telling you: "They WILL fear you!".
I hope you find this helpfull. If you have any more questions or just need general advice with anything dota related feel free to ask . I also forgot one thing. When using suicide, try to walk to the enemy and then target the ground for suicide. If you simply press suicide and then the enemy, they will hear: "Do not run, we are your friend!" so they will know you are trying to suicide, but if you just run towards them and then use suicide fast it will be to late for them. Although they generally don't let you get to close, I thought of mentioning this so that the answer would be complete.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, especially force staff seems a good idea, never thought of it :) could you also tell me about your preferred item pack please ?

Comment: Well, the core items are clarity potions(theses will get you going early game:P),force staff(usefull not only for pushing enemies into mines but also pushing yourself and getting the suicide kills. If you plan on using suicide a lot -and not only for suicide-, bloodstone helps with both stying dead for a shorter time and it's main uses,although it's pretty expensive)and Aghanim. Depending on the enemy team you should figure out which to buy first, aghanim or force staff. If you have problems farming obviously force staff is a better choice. Well these are the core items.

Comment: Optional items: go wild. Hex is great. Eul is great-rise them in the air and put bombs where they land. Or if you are carry maniac like me, go dps if you can get early aghanim. After lvl 11 with aghanim it's one remote bomb and you get all the creeps. So you can farm like crazy.Almost forgot. Travel man!! Travel+aghanim and you are some crazy farmer going wild. You will have so many money in such short time you can go full dps build desolator butterfly rapier FTW anything you can think of, but I wouldn't recommend this if you are new to dota(I do this for fun). Just go standard item build.

Comment: Sure np .. but remember .. have fun with it :)